# Django - manually build HttpResponse, but want to use a template too

Tags: python, django, django-templates

When returning an `HttpResponse` object with `render_to_response` you can provide a template and it will use that template and fill in all the `{{ variables }}` you've set within your template.

If I want to build my `HttpResponse` object manually, is it possible to still use one of my templates in my template directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string), you will get rendered string. You can pass the returned string to the `HttpResponse`.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

...

rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
response = HttpResponse(rendered)
```

Comment: Yup, this does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can use Django's [template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#module-django.template.loader) to load your template as a `Template` object, and then [render it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) to a string, which you pass to `HttpResponse`:

```
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.template.loader import get_template

def my_view(request):
    temp = get_template('/path/to/template.html')
    result = temp.render(Context({'context': 'here'})
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

*EDIT*

Just noticed @falsetru's answer above - that's probably a better and shorter way!

Comment: After posting the question (as it often happens) I discovered your method to achieving what I wanted and was just testing it out when I came back to my SO question. Your method works wonderfully, but as you say, @falsetru shows a slightly more elegant method.